# Bootstrap form layout breaks when displaying help text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using Bootstrap 3 forms. In a normal Bootstrap form with field labels on top on input fields (no `form-inline`, no `form-horizontal`) I want to be able to display a flexible number of controls in the same row. For example:

- 4 controls on a full width screen
- 2 controls on a medium size screen
- 1 control on small screens

To get this we can use a Bootstrap `row` to group all four controls and appropiate `col-xx-x` classes for each control. See code below.

The problem with this layout is that when the controls are displayed stacked (more than one row) and the `help-block` used to display errors in controls is displayed the layout of the control just below the help text is pushed one position to the right. The reason for this is that those controls share the same row and the extra height added by the help message fills one space in the lower row. See the example provided.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <form>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
          <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email">
          <span id="errorMessage" class="help-block" style="display: none">This is the error message</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
          <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
          <label for="other">Other</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Other">
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
    <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="function showError() {document.getElementById('errorMessage').style.display = 'inline'};showError();">
    Show error message in email control
  </button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I have experimented with `form-inline` forms, but then the help text is displayed on the right side of the control instead of below.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this is what you are looking for...

```css
.no-padding {
  padding-left: 0 !important;
  padding-right: 0 !important;
}

.no-right-margin {
  margin-right: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <form>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
          <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email">
          <span id="errorMessage" class="help-text" style="display: none">This is the error message</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
          <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 no-padding">
        <div class="row no-right-margin">
          <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
            <label for="other">Other</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Other">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
    <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="function showError() {document.getElementById('errorMessage').style.display = 'inline'};showError();">
    Show error message in email control
  </button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I think this may leave a control right to "Other" field incorrectly vertical aligned with it, since it will not go down to leave space for the help text, and adds lot of boilerplate. I have experimented  adding a `position:absolute` to the `span` with the `help-block` class and it is working, but I don't know if this will start to break other things around.

Comment: @DavidCasillas Absolute position is not a good solution all the time.It cause problems in responsive, You need to have `clear:both` for the `:after`  or `:before` of the element that takes little much height. Thats what bootstrap `row` does, Thats why previous lines can't bother the position of `row` element. If you are using bootstrap I suggest you to go with the bootstrap which is responsive effective

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue and went with the absolute positioning you hinted at. Here is my bootstrap override

```
.form-group {
  position: relative;
  .help-block { position: absolute; right: 2rem; bottom: -3rem }
}
```

I put it the right so when the field are stacked it doesn't clutter with the label.
I haven't determined the full consequences of this in all contexts but for the issue at hand it seems to work well. Future pages may make me tweak the values for one reason or another.